# Can't find where the error is in my binary search implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, binary-search

Task. The goal in this code problem is to implement the binary search algorithm.

Input Format. The first line of the input contains an integer , the second line is a sequence 0 < 1 < . . . < −1 of  pairwise distinct positive integers in increasing order. The third line contains an integer k, and the fourth line contains  positive integers 0, 1, . . . , −1.

Constraints. 1 ≤ ,  ≤ 10^4; 1 ≤  ≤ 10^9 for all 0 ≤  < ; 1 ≤  ≤ 10^9 for all 0 ≤  < ;

Output Format. For all  from 0 to  − 1, output an index 0 ≤  ≤  − 1 such that  =  or −1 if there is no such index.

16 out of 36 cases passed.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    terminal: false
});

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
rl.once('line', line => {
    const n = parseInt(line, 10);
    rl.once('line', line => {
        let arr;
        if (line.toString() === '') {
            arr = [];
        } else {
            arr = line.toString().split(' ').slice(0, n).map(Number);
        }

        rl.once('line', line => {
            const k = parseInt(line, 10);

            rl.once('line', line => {
                const keys = line.toString().split(' ').map(Number);
                const result = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                    result.push(binarySearch(arr, keys[i]));
                }

                const res = result.join(' ');
                const maxLength = 50000;

                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += maxLength) {
                    process.stdout.write(res.slice(i, i + maxLength));
                }

                process.stdout.write('\n');
                process.exit();
            })
        })
    })
});

function binarySearch(arr, key) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return -1;
    let l = 0;
    let r = arr.length - 1;
    let m;
    while (l <= r) {
        m = Math.ceil((l + r) / 2);
        if (arr[m] === key) {
            return m;
        }
        if (arr[m] > key) r = m - 1;
        if (arr[m] < key) l = m + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That's what I got in the result:
Failed case #17/36: Wrong answer

(Time used: 0.06/5.00, memory used: 46145536/536870912.)

Comment: try `floor` instead of `ceil`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it, which makes me wonder if it's not simply some clerical error (copy/paste issue, forgetting to save, etc...).  If it is definitely not that, you will probably need access to the failing test case input(s)/output(s) to further debug.

Comment: @ITgoldman I tried to use floor instead of ceil and it didn't change anything

Comment: @Amadeus Does it have to be written in JavaScript? Maybe the JavaScript runtime used for testing interprets some parts of the code in different ways than we can expect?

Comment: @user20276305 The task can be implemented in any language. Maybe you're right, I don't even know what could be wrong.